# Calling document.ready function of file from another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two html files. One file has a table which is constantly updated by the script written in the same. The table part is in body of the html and its contents are updated once the document.ready is executed. I want to run the document.ready of file from the another file and show the table(which is constantly updating and present in another file) in that file.

**FILE -1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#maindiv').load('http://somesite/index.html #tableId');


       });
 </script>
<body>
<div id="maindiv"></div>
</body>
```

**FILE- 2(index.html page)**

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function(){

          $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
          some_function(true);
          setInterval(function(){some_function(false)},500);
      });

      //Some Global Variables Declared

var some_function= function(getAll){
//Accessing and using the above variables
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="tableId">
<table>
 ......
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The answer of this depends on how you're loading the second HTML document. Are you talking about loading the 2nd file within an iframe on the same page? Or are you talking about someone visiting the 2nd page in a separate tab/window?

Comment: Thanks joeltine for looking into this. No I am not using iframe here (Should I??). As of now I got the structure of the table, in the another html page using document.ready ...$('#maindiv').load('http://site/index.html #table-id') ... but the contents of the table are not being updated. Meanwhile in the other page, the contents of the table are updated once the document.ready function is executed. I am interested in calling that document.ready function from this file.

Comment: @phaigeim look at my example below on how you call functions from another file with having them in the global scope. Also posting some code could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If I got your right. You should do [global functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). Lets say you have the scenario below.

File one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      doSomething();     
});

function doSomething() {
    //doing something
}
```

File two

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

**EDIT**
If you want to get html from another page you can use the jQuery `.load()`. You would have to have the javascript that makes it dynamic on the file you "import" it to.

file one html

```
<div class="load-table-here"></div>
```

file two html

```
<table class="you-want-me"></table>
```

you load it like this

**UPDATE**

```
$('.load-table-here').load('path/file-two.html .you-want-me', function() {
      some_fuction(true);
      setInterval(function(){some_function(false)},500);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is correct, but I want something different. My another file is an index.html which has table and the content in this dynamically changing. I have to access that html page and display the data and that must also change dyanamically.

Comment: The data of the table is inserted dynamically through script running in the same file. I have to run that script from other file too. I am getting the structure of the table, but I am not getting the contents

Comment: Thanks alot, but Initially there is no data in table and the new data is always appended, removed or changed by executing the script. Though I use your updated code, the table is still empty..

Comment: @phaigeim It's so hard do say what's wrong when not knowing how you populate your table with data. Could you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery.load documentation, look at the "Script Execution" section: http://api.jquery.com/load/. The important example to point out here is,

> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being
>   loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> ```
> $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
> ```

So, in other words, the scripts loaded for your other file are never executed and can never update your new table.